# Como pegar mais de um valor do banco de dados e salvar em uma ComboBox mais de um valor retornado?

Tags: java

Estou com uma dúvida que é a seguinte, quando eu faço uma consulta no banco ele pode me retornar mais de dois nomes, e só consigo pegar um.
A idéia é filtrar os nomes dos médicos pelo tipo de médico(Neurocirurgião, Entre outros) e depois pegar esses nomes e colocar em uma ComboBox.

Aqui está o código porém retorna apenas um nome.

Criei uma função para isso.

```
    public String tipoMedico(String tipo)
    {
    try{
    Statement comando = cone.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = comando.executeQuery("SELECT Nome,Tipo FROM `medicos`                    
    WHERE Tipo='"+tipo+"';");//Se tiver dois médicos do mesmo tipo, era  
    para retornar mais de um nome, quero saber como pegar todos os nomes  
    que retornar.

    while(rs.next()) {

              String Tipo = rs.getString("Tipo");
                String Nome1 = rs.getString("Nome");

                if(tipo.equals(Tipo)){                    

                 return Nome1;
                  }
    }}
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro na Conexão com o Banco de 
    Dados");
    }
     return "Não encontrado";
    }
```

---

Depois chamar os Nomes em uma ComboBox.

```
   private void cbTipoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
   String nome =  
   dado.tipoMedico(cbTipo.getItemAt(cbTipo.getSelectedIndex()));
   String tipo = cbTipo.getItemAt(cbTipo.getSelectedIndex());
    switch(tipo)
   {
    case "Neurocirurgião": cbDoutor.removeAllItems();
    cbDoutor.addItem(nome);//Aqui eu adiciono o nome retornado do banco   
    na comboBox
      break;
      case "Clinico Geral": cbDoutor.removeAllItems();
       cbDoutor.addItem(nome);
      break;

     }}
```

Comment: cara, o problema tá no seu return. Você tá familiarizado com a estrutura `LIst`?

Comment: Você tá retornando uma string simples do banco.Um combobox espera uma combomodel ou um vetor de strings.

Comment: Outra coisa, não se deve misturar as camadas, onde for pra pesquisar no banco, deve ser somente para consulta e funções de banco, botar optionpane em método de banco e com retorno definido é uma péssima prática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que você retorna no primeiro incremento do `ResultSet`. Então sugiro que você retorne um `List` de `String`:

```
public List<String> tipoMedico(String tipo) {
List<String> medicos = new ArrayList<>();

try {
  Statement comando = cone.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = comando.executeQuery("SELECT Nome,Tipo FROM `medicos` WHERE Tipo ='" + tipo + "'  ;");

  while (rs.next()) {
    String tipoEncontrado = rs.getString("Tipo");
    String nome = rs.getString("Nome");

    if (tipoEncontrado.equals(tipoEncontrado)) {
      medicos.add(nome);
    }
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na Conexão com o Banco de Dados");
}

return medicos;
```

}

E adicione o resultado ao combo da seguinte forma:

```
private void cbTipoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  List<String> nomes = dado.tipoMedico(cbTipo.getItemAt(cbTipo.getSelectedIndex()));
  String tipo = cbTipo.getItemAt(cbTipo.getSelectedIndex());

  cbDoutor.removeAllItems();

  for (String nome : nomes) {
    cbDoutor.addItem(nome);
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual é a idéia de dar -1 nessa resposta e nem deixar um comentário do que pode ser melhorado ou que teoricamente está errado?

Comment: Nossa cara muito Obrigado Mesmo, vou tentar aqui, Enquanto ao DiegoFm nossa cara valeu pela dica, eu criei uma classe propria pro banco sim, mas não sabia dessa do JOptionPane muito obrigado, Depois volto com o resultado Obrigado Sorack

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ e + 1 (útil) caso essa solução lhe atenda, para que possa ser utilizada como solução para outras pessoas também!

Comment: Deu certo de Listar mais que 1 valor, porém agora esta com um problema, toda vez que seleciono um tipo na check box ele está adicionando o mesmo nome novamente, se eu selecionar neurocirurgião 2x está aparecendo os nomes em dobro

Comment: Você tá dando o removeAllItens antes de adicionar?

Comment: @AndersonHenrique já cogitou criar um comboboxmodel baseado numa classe medico? Não é complicado e torna seu código mais organizado.

Comment: Era isso mesmo esqueci do removeAllItens, muito obrigado mesmo irei marcar aqui, onde marca isso? Sou novo aqui, criei hoje

Comment: Ao lado da resposta. Caso queira melhor a qualidade do código você pode criar um model como o @diegofm comentou e também separar as classes. Ah, no seu exemplo original tinham variáveis iniciando com letra maiúscula, pela convenção da antiga Sun você deve sempre iniciar nomes de variável com letra minúscula

Comment: @diegofm então cara, estou no inicio de java na faculdade, tem muitas coisas que não sei, pra falar verdade a maioria do que ja sei aprendi na internet mesmo

Comment: @AndersonHenrique entendo, mas fica a dica, sempre procure separar as responsabilidades, por exemplo, nesse seu código, eu teria uma classe Médico e outra para especialidade, geralmente a relação de médico para especialidade é nxn(médicos pode tem várias especialidades, e vice-versa).